# Paint bubbling and peeling on a steel door

Tags: painting

I have a steel front door, behind a solid glass storm door. It gets so hot that paint bubbles and peels. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet on "poor preparation/paint job" (given that preparation is 90% of a good paint job.)

If you wanted to, you could use a high-temperature paint such as engine enamel (typically good to 450F or more) (no need to go for the exhaust-manifold paints unless your doorframe is charring, I think.) I strongly suspect that's not really needed; you could put a magnet on a thermometer and stick it to the door to get a reading for what the temperature actually is some sunny day.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the glass door, you can buy vent kits to install in your outer door. What color is the door? Maybe you could paint it a lighter color.  Maybe you could plant a tree that could provide some shade in front of it.

Comment: Good ideas, but there's a chance it was just a poor paint job to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some vents that I can install in the bottom and top of the storm door. Hopefully this will help some, and it will will be an easy option to try, before more expensive options such as a complete main door/storm door replacement.